# Appending row values of a table with columns of another table

Tags: mysql, rows

I have a table T1 with standard columns like name, email, phone_number. The custom fields are store in custom_fields table as key, value.

I need to have key name of custom_fields as column name on actual table. How can I achieve this

**Table T1**

id  name  email

1   John  john@example.com

2   Sam   same@mydomain.com

**custom_fields**

id  T1_id  key       value

1   1      Age       32

2   1      Job Title CEO

3   2      Age       40

4   2      Car Owned Ford EcoSport

**Required**

T1_id  name  email                  age  job_title       car_owned

1      John  john@example.com        32   CEO            Not specified

2      Sam   same@mydomain.com       40   Not specified  Ford EcoSport

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've used this for now but its not exactly what I want. 

select T1.*, (select GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(`key`,' = ',`value`) ORDER BY `key` ASC SEPARATOR '; ') from custom_fields where T1_id=T1.id group by `T1_id`) as cust_fields from T1

Answer (score 0):

You should use the table  custom_fields two time one for job and one for car

```
select  t1.id, t1.name, t1.email, t2.value, t3.value 
from  t1 
inner join custom_fields t2 on t1.id = t2.t1_id and  t2.key = 'Job Title' 
inner join custom_fields t3 on t1.id = t3.t1_id and  t3.key = 'Car Owned'
```